# How to configure multiple vmwares to run on one server?

Tags: vmware

I have a Windows Server 2012 with only one ethernet card, and a VMWare workstation 11 installed on this server box.

I need to run multiple VMWares on this server box and connect to these VMWares from other machines within the same network of the server box. Thus, I need to assign an individual IP address to each VMWare.

I tried to make the network setting in each VMWare be `bridged`, but I can't ping the VMWares from the host system (the server box).

Is there any missing configuration?

Do I need to have more than one ethernet card? Or can more than one VMWare take different IPs shared with the host?